# gt table - newline in cell

Tags: r, newline, gt

I try to force a newline in a gt cell using R gt package. In gt documentation it is described as possible to do it for column labels using `cols_label()`

```
 # example
 gt_tbl %>%
  cols_label(
    col = html("text1,<br>text2")
   )
```

But in cells I could not find a way to do it. I tried by adding \n or 
 without success.

```
library(gt)

# dummy data
dat <- tibble(
  a=1:3,
  b=c("a","b c","d e f")
)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      a b    
  <int> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b c  
3     3 d e f

# with \n
dat %>% 
  mutate(b=str_replace_all(b," ","\n")) %>% 
  gt()

# with <br>
dat %>% 
  mutate(b=str_replace_all(b," ","<br>")) %>% 
  gt()
```

Always the same table that is generated :

[image]

Expected results :

[image]

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We need to call [fmt_markdown](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/fmt_markdown.html), see below:

> Any Markdown-formatted text in the incoming cells will be transformed to the appropriate output type during render when using *fmt_markdown()*.

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(b = str_replace_all(b, " ", "<br>")) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  fmt_markdown(columns = TRUE)
```

[image]

---

Or a workaround: split into new rows then call `gt()`:

```
dat %>% 
  separate_rows(b) %>% 
  mutate(a = ifelse(duplicated(a), "", a)) %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]

Comment: New syntax in 0.3.0 is `fmt_markdown(columns = everything())` or some other select helper (`starts_with("xyz"`)